# I want to select Name and Phone number from contacts list and display in my app

Tags: android-contacts

I am able to select name but I am confused how to select phone number when name has more than 1 phone numer associated with it. Below is my code.

```
public class getName extends Activity {
//permission
//<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private static final int PICK_CONTACT = 0;
EditText Name;
EditText Phone;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    Phone = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // to read contacts add android.permission.READ_CONTACTS
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, People.CONTENT_URI);
            //intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0); 
        }
    });
}

public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    switch (reqCode) {
    case (PICK_CONTACT) :
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri contactData = data.getData();
            Cursor c =  managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(People.Phones.NAME));
                Name.setText(name);

                Uri uri = data.getData();
                Cursor cursor=managedQuery(uri, null, null, null, null);

                while (cursor.moveToNext()) { 
                    String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( 
                            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID)); 
                    String hasPhone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( 
                            ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)); 
                    if (Boolean.parseBoolean(hasPhone)) { 
                        // You know have the number so now query it like this
                        Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query( 
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
                                null, 
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ contactId, 
                                null, null); 
                        while (phones.moveToNext()) { 
                            String phoneNumber = phones.getString( 
                                    phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));              
                        } 
                        phones.close(); 
                    } 
                }




            }

        }
    break;
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you uncomment the second line in your button onClick you should see a list with Contact name and their number. SO, you can directly select a number

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, People.CONTENT_URI);
 intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
```